# .on(click) with attribute setting not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set an attribute of "checked" on a checkbox.

The code:

```
$(".ui.toggle" ).on( "click", function() {

  if ($('#ownplace').not(':checked')) {
    $('#ownplace').attr('checked', true );
  }
  else {
    $('#ownplace').prop('checked', false);
  }

});
```

It checkes the box alright, but then it wont uncheck. I have tried multiple solutions including using the attr instead of prop - and yes I have conducted a search, but nothing seems to clarify this particular problem.

**EDIT**

I need to be able to capture if the checkbox is checked, like so:

```
if($data['ownplace'] == checked) {
      $user->ownplace = $data['ownplace'];
 }
```

This workes: `$('#ownplace').prop('checked', !$('#ownplace').is(':checked'));` but it doesn't set the checked attribute on the field, so i cant check if its checked or not.

None of the solutions are setting `checked="checked"` on the input field, so that `on click` will make `<input class="ownplace" type="checkbox">` will be `<input class="ownplace" type="checkbox" checked="checked">`.

The `.prop` doesn't do that, and only toggles css I guess.

Patrick

Comment: Try `var box = $("#ownplace"); box.prop("checked", !box.prop("checked"));` - this should toggle it. But that aside, don't you think it's odd that you use `.attr` in one but `.prop` in the other?

Comment: Use `prop('checked', true);`. Please search before you post question, this has been asked 546543 times.

Comment: Properly debug your code: Use alert() or consloe.log() methods to check wheter your selector is correct and in whate case you end up.

Comment: **Shortcut:** `$('#ownplace').prop('checked', !$('#ownplace').is(':checked'));`

Comment: Hi, thnx for the answers. This wont work, as i need the attr to be set as checked="checked" in an input field. This seems just to toggle the check mark, but not acctually setting the checked status. This is needed to be able to capture the checked status when posted.

Comment: At this point you probably want to include a minimal snippet that demonstrates what you're struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prop()` function instead:

```
$('#ownplace').prop('checked', true );
```

**EXPLANATION**

Using attr() will work too (but your if clause is wrong), but, prop() is most recommended.

If you want to check for the checkboxe's state use `is(:checked)`

```
if (!$('#ownplace').is(':checked')) {
   $('#ownplace').prop('checked', true );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
 $('#ownplace').attr('checked', true );
```

To :

```
 $('#ownplace').prop('checked', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `prop` instead of `attr`

`$('#ownplace').prop('checked', true );`

`attr` only works in **jQuery 1.6** or before

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely the issue is with the `if` condition. Use:

```
!$('#ownplace').is(':checked')   //instead of $('#ownplace').not(':checked')
```

Then use the following to check the checkbox:

```
$('#ownplace').prop('checked', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems queryselector for .ui.toggle may cause some problem. Here is the JSFiddle, where you can see for .ui-toggle the code works fine but for .ui.toggle it doesn't.

https://jsfiddle.net/krnitesh/uovoykya/

```
<button class="ui.toggle" >Click Me</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="ownplace" checked="true" />

<button class="ui-toggle" >Click Me</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="ownplace2" checked="true" />
$('.ui.toggle' ).on("click", function() {
console.log(($('#ownplace').is(':checked')));

$('#ownplace').prop("checked", !($('#ownplace').is(':checked')));

});

$('.ui-toggle' ).on("click", function() {
console.log(($('#ownplace2').is(':checked')));

$('#ownplace2').prop("checked", !($('#ownplace2').is(':checked')));

});
```